# Swift chat connection with params using webSockets

Tags: swift, sockets, websocket, chat, vapor

I have two apps, client (iOS app) & server (Vapor app). I am trying to pass **username** & **userID** to server with webSocket when app connected to webSocket.
The problem is... I don't know how to send params with webSocket, I'm only able to send data with message as structure, but that's not what I want.

**My iOS client connect method:**

```
    private var webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask? = nil

    func connect(completion: @escaping ()->() = { }) {
        guard webSocketTask == nil else { return }

        self.username = "Name"
        self.userID = UUID().uuidString
        let url = URL(string: "ws://localhost:8080/connect")!
        webSocketTask = URLSession.shared.webSocketTask(with: url)
        webSocketTask?.receive(completionHandler: onReceive)
        webSocketTask?.resume()
    }
```

**My Vapor server method:**

```
var clientConnections = Set<WebSocket>()

app.webSocket("connect") { req, client in
    client.pingInterval = .seconds(10)
    clientConnections.insert(client)
    
    client.onClose.whenComplete { _ in
        clientConnections.remove(client)
    }
    
    client.onText { ws, text in
        do {
            guard let data = text.data(using: .utf8) else { return }

            let incomingMessage = try JSONDecoder().decode(SubmittedChatMessage.self, from: data)
            let outgoingMessage = ReceivingChatMessage(
                message: incomingMessage.message,
                user   : incomingMessage.user.name,
                userID : incomingMessage.user.userId,
                gender : incomingMessage.user.gender)
            
            let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(outgoingMessage)
            
            guard let jsonString = String(data: json, encoding: .utf8) else { return }

            for connection in clientConnections {
                connection.send(jsonString)
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `webSocketTask.send(.data(<#T##Data#>), completionHandler: <#T##(Error?) -> Void#>)`

Comment: @SPatel But that's send something AFTER connection, that's already working. But I need to share data on connection step, not after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send data on connection you'll need to pass it in the URL. You can either pass it as query parameters (`ws://localhost:8080/connect?name=Alice&username=alice`) or pass it in the URL itself (`ws://localhost:8080/connect/users/<userID>`)